# Argument is not Optional (open office basic macro)

Tags: basic

can you help me work out whats wrong in this function?

```
Function TrueSolarTime(eqtime As Double, longitude As Double, _
        timeZone As Double, hours As Double, minutes As Double) As Double

    dim time_offset as double
    dim x as double

    time_offset = eqtime - (4 * longitude) + (60 * timeZone)

    TrueSolarTime = hours * 60 + minutes + time_offset


End Function
```

Comment: What line number had the error?